# Difference b/w method="POST" and @method('PUT') in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am use a form with attribute `method="POST"` to update the record in laravel. But updating of record is not working. Then after putting `@method('PUT')` inside the form, record updating is working fine.

I just want to know about `@method('PUT')` and when to use it in form of Laravel application.

**Not Working**

```
<form action="{{ route('student.update',$studentData->id) }}" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

**Working Fine**

```
<form action="{{ route('student.update',$studentData->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `@method(...)` is called [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing) in Laravel and is a requirement because HTML forms do no support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` for the [`method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) attribute.

The value of the `@method` is sent as part of the form request and used by Laravel to determine how to process the form submission.

Comment: Further more I would like to add this link from [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers) which define the resource controllers including their usage.

Answer (score 1):

What does your web.php file look like ?
If you're using  `Route::resource('student', SomeController::class)`

POST method will hit your `student.create` route, while PUT will hit your `student.update` route.

You can check your routes and their respective methods in detail by running `php artisan route:list` in your console

Comment: post method would be @method('PUT') or method='PUT'?

Comment: post method is just a regular `method=post` in the html form.
You only need to use method spoofing for `PUT` `DELETE` `PATCH`

Comment: @David only `PUT` and `PATCH`. `DELETE` is a regular method in HTTP

Comment: That's correct, my bad

Answer (score 1):

See if you are using resource routes for CRUD operation then it will include GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods so when you are inserting data for first time using form that time you will use POST method and when you are doing update operation that time you have to use **@method('put')** because resource route will support only put method, you can update using POST also but you have to make separate route for that like we make general post route **Route::post(...)**

Comment: Please the question so we can help rhe other